# How to remove white noise and Connected Component extraction in OpenCV?

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, opencv3.0, opencv

I am working on a sudoku solver that takes input from a video camera(Laptop) and processes it, parses the sudoku image as a list of lists, solves it, and projects back the solution onto the sheet.

I am now at the point where I need to recognize each digit from the image. I'm using the MNIST dataset to train my model which expects each input image in the shape of (28, 28, 1), I am successfully able to locate each digit and extract it but performing any kind of threshold on the digit leads to a lot of noise around the digit, which ultimately leads to misclassification by my model.

[image: Warped and Thresholded Sudoku image]

Is there any method to get rid of the white noise and only extract the digit from the square and then feed it to the Keras Model.

I think this can be achieved by using the `cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats` by extracting the largest connected component but I do not know how the method works (and the arguments it expects or the output of the method) and I couldn't find a good explanation on how to use it.

If there is an alternative way other than using `cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats` that produces better results please do suggest if not please explain how the `cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats` the method works or please point me towards a good resource that helps me understand it and how to use it for my specific case.

PS. If you think the MNIST isn't a good dataset for this task please do tell why and any other dataset that may achieve the task of recognizing digits.

Comment: You should reduce the noise before thresholding, that is always the easier choice.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the noise you can use an [erosion](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaeb1e0c1033e3f6b891a25d0511362aeb). It is used to filter out white pixel and "fill in the (white) gap".
Every white areas will be smaller, and very small area will disapeared. Digits will look thiner.

You can then dilate [dilate](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga4ff0f3318642c4f469d0e11f242f3b6c) to get an image more similar to the original one (thiner digit will become fatter and look like the original one, even if there remain little differences).

This operation is know as an opening. See https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html

Example:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('input.jpg',0)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(img,kernel,iterations = 1)
dilatation = cv2.dilate(erosion,kernel,iterations = 1)
```

**Edit** a kernel of (3,3) for the dilatation makes the image less blurry.

### Input

[image: Input]

### Erosion

[image: Erosion]

### Dilatation

[image: Dilatation]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am familiar with dilation after erosion(which is nothing but opening as you've mentioned) even after doing so there is an ample amount of noise in the image due to which my model is misclassifying it...Most misclassifications are something like predicting 6 as 8/5 or 7 as 2/1...is there any method to only extract the digit from the square? or can this be achieved by using `connectedComponentsWithStats`?

Comment: After the erosion there is not much noise in the image. if you were able to locate the squares before hands you can take the eroded image and feed it to a svm or whatever keras model you are using. Even a template matching would work here, no need for neural network.

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore the small blobs (small width, small height and/or small area). At the same time, you can ignore the large ones.

[image]

To skip the grid lines, it is advisable to reconstruct the grid geometry (use the characters to locate the grid columns/rows, and possibly detect the long straight lines), and only keep the blobs wholly inside a cell.